# Calling an Oracle DB function with IN, OUT, IN/OUT parameters and return value in Python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have been given a function that can be called the following, i.e.         using 'SQL Oracle Developer':

```
--set serveroutput on size 2000;
declare
    theId VARCHAR(20);
    theKey VARCHAR(20) := '';
    theName VARCHAR(20) := '';
    theEmail VARCHAR(20) := '';
    theDob DATE := '';
    theVal NUMBER;
begin
    theId := Package.FunctionName(
        theKey,
        theName,
        theEmail,
        theDob,
        theVal
    );
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(theId);
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(theKey);
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(theVal);
    exception
        when others then
            RAISE;
end;
```

Now, I am supposed to call this function in Python using cx_Oracle.

To do so I've tried below approach but can not get it to work:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
function = '''
    BEGIN
        theKey := inout_theKey;
        theName := in_theName;
        theEmail := in_theEmail;
        theDob := in_theDob;
        theVal := out_theVal;
        theId := Package.FunctionName(theKey, theName theEmail, theDob, theVal)
        :out_theId := theId;
        :inout_theKey := theKey;
        :out_theVal := theVal;
    END;'''

out_theId = cursor.var(str)
out_theVal = cursor.var(int)
inout_theKey = cursor.var(str)
inout_theKey.setvalue(0, '')
cursor.execute(
    function, 
    inout_theKey=inout_theKey, 
    in_theName='', 
    in_theEmail='', 
    in_theDob='', 
    out_theId=out_theId, 
    out_theVal=out_theVal)
_logger.debug(out_theId.getvalue())
```

This fails with the error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Maybe one can point me in the right direction where my bindings are incorrect?

---

For what it's worth I've also tried to add the DECLARE statement to function , i.e.

```
function = '''
    DECLARE 
       theId VARCHAR(20) := out_theId;  
       theKey VARCHAR(20) := inout_ttheKey; 
       theName VARCHAR(20) := in_theName; 
       theEmail VARCHAR(20) := in_theEmail; 
       theDob DATE := in_theDob; 
       theVal NUMBER := out_theVal;  
    BEGIN  

       theId := Package.FunctionName(theKey, theName, theEmail, theDob, theVal); 

       :out_theId := theId; 
       :inout_theKey := theKey; 
       :out_theVal := theVal; 
    END;'''
```

which still provides me with the same result (`illegal variable name/number`).

The connection to the database via cx_Oracle is working (verified with several other sql statements).

Comment: Details matter.  Share a complete set of code that we can run.  Include SQL to create the necessary function.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey @ChristopherJones, thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, above is all that is known by me from the given function since it has been provided by a third party to me. However, I was now able to answer the question that I've got (_what is wrong with the binding / how to actually call such a function_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a rather simple solution to this:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
function = 'Package.FunctionName'

inout_theKey = ''
in_theName = ''
in_theEmail = ''
in_theDob = ''
out_theVal = cursor.var(int)  # default type is str, else define the type like this

out_theId = cursor.callfunc(function, str, [
    inout_theKey, 
    in_theName, 
    in_theEmail, 
    in_theDob, 
    out_theVal
])

_logger.debug(out_theId)
_logger.debug(inout_theKey)
_logger.debug(out_theVal)
```

Essentially you just need to provide the function name (`function`), the expected return value (`str` in this case) and a list of IN, OUT and IN/OUT parameters as per the functions definition to a `callfunc` call.

Ref: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.callfunc and https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html#plsqlfunc